# Problem on Work and Time

Tags: linear-algebra

If 5 men and 2 boys  work together, a piece of work can be completed in one day. If 3 men and 6 boys work together, it can also be completed in one day. How long will it take a boy, alone, to do the work?

Is this a correct way to start answering the problem?

$5m+3b=1\\
3m+6b=1$

Comment: What is M ?     $~~~~~$

Comment: You do have to be clear what $M$ and $B$ are - but those equations are part of a possible method of solution.

Comment: Yes, but you must be clear about what $M$ and $B$ are (unless you're clear about that you might end up with a flawed conclusion). Just picking equations out of thin air is never a good way to start a solution...

Answer (score 0):

No, just picking equations out of thin air is no good start. You must be clear about what $M$ and $B$ are and give a motivation for the equations first.

Let $M$ be the amount of work a man can do in a day and $B$ be the amount of work a boy can do in a day. The unit of work is the work at hand.

In one day then $5$ men and $3$ boys would be able to produce a work of $5M+3B$ and they are assumed to be able to pull out $1$ unit of work, which gives the equation $5M+3B=1$. In similar way we get the equation $3M+6B=1$.

Solving these equations we get $M=1/7$ and $B=2/21$. This means that in $d$ days a boy is able to pull off $2d/21$ units of work and the question were how many days to pull off $1$ unit of work which gives the equation $2d/21=1$ which has the solution $d = 21/2$ that is it would take him $10{1\over2}$ days to complete the task.

---

A reason it's important to not just pull equations out of thin air and not explain what $M$ and $B$ are is that one could think that they would represent the time to do the work which is **not** correct. That way one would come to the questionable solution that it would take a single boy less time than a larger team to complete the work.